# Python class self variable not transfering to function (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

In this code `on_raw_reaction_add()` gets `self.server` as `None` but in `on_raw_reaction_remove()` it does get what I have assinged to it in `__init__()`. Easy solution is to do the same line inside that function, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work like it should to my knowledge.

Edit: Tried with `self.client.server_id` didn't work either

Edit II: It doesn't work in `on_raw_reaction_remove()` either as I said earlier

> Edit III: Found out why. The bot is not running yet when called and thus `get_guild` is `None`. Duh.

```py
class reactionsCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.server = self.client.get_guild(client.server_id)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, reaction):
        #Private events
        for i in range(2):
            if reaction.message_id == self.client.pri_message[i].id:
                print('Someone reacted to pri_message ', i, ' with ', str(reaction.emoji))
                if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
                    if reaction.user_id != self.client.user.id:
                        member = self.server.get_member(reaction.user_id)
                        userstr = member.display_name
                        if userstr in self.client.pri_not_sure[i]:
                            await self.client.pri_message[i].remove_reaction('❔', member)
                        self.client.pri_attending[i].append(userstr)
                        try:
                            await self.client.pri_message[i].remove_reaction('❌', member)
                        except:
                            pass
                        print(member.name, ' added to pri_attending ', i)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, reaction):
        #Private events
        for i in range(2):
            if reaction.message_id == self.client.pri_message[i].id:
                if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
                    member = self.server.get_member(reaction.user_id)
                    print(member.name, ' removed from pri_attending ', i)
                    userstr = member.display_name
                    self.client.pri_attending[i].remove(userstr)
```

Comment: Make sure  `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove` are called AFTER `self.client.get_guild(client.server_id)` function call has ended. Since the functions you defined are asynchronous this might be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but not the problem in this case.

Comment: If you've solved it, post the solution as answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, this is happening because `get_guild` is being called before the bot is connected to the discord API services.  You can solve this by including an `on_ready` event that will trigger when the bot connects:

```
class reactionsCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        self.server = self.client.get_guild(client.server_id)

    ...
```